# has me beat vs. has me beaten vs. beats me

Tags: past-participles, synonyms, causative-verbs

An LA Times column titled "[A Word, Please: Microsoft unveils top 10 grammar mistakes, but its editing tools aren’t perfect](http://www.latimes.com/socal/burbank-leader/opinion/tn-blr-me-aword-20170720-story.html)" has this passage:

> ...
>
> Microsoft’s No. 1 most common grammar mistake is putting an extra
> space between words. Not between sentences (which is a no-no in
> professional publishing), but between words.
>
> Well, that’s not a grammar mistake. But it is a common mistake, and it
> is easier for a computer to catch it. So I suppose Editor Bot of
> Tomorrow **has me beat** there.
>
> ...

Can the last sentence be replaced with either of these to convey the same meaning?

> (1) So I suppose Editor Bot of Tomorrow **has me beaten** there.
>
> (2) So I suppose Editor Bot of Tomorrow **beats me** there.

Answer (score 2):

My gut response would yes to the first, no to the second.

Linguistically, proper English is whatever phrase makes sense and sounds right to a native speaker, so I would say that "So I suppose Editor Bot of Tomorrow has me beaten there" conveys the same meaning, as it is already clear in the first sentence that "beat" is past tense due to the presence of "has." The second replacement would be invalid, as "So I suppose Editor Bot of Tomorrow beats me there" would convey the meaning that the Bot is somehow ahead of the speaker metaphorically, rather than that the speaker is confused or stumped by the Bot.